# Change other Column value when apply on Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, apply

So I'm a bit lost. I have basically something like the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'period':['Wk20-20','Wkend', 'Wk42-20', 'Q'],
'value': [None, '21-12', None, '4']})
```

```
    period  value
0   Wk20-20 None
1   Wkend   21-12
2   Wk42-20 None
3   Q       4
```

Now I want to split the 'Wk20-20'-like values into 'Week' for the period column and 20-20 as value.

I try to apply the following function:

```
def transform(row):
    
    if re.match(r'Wk\d\d-\d\d', str(row["Description"])):
        print(type(row['Period_Date']))
        row['Period_Date'] = row['Description'].split('Wk')[1]
        return 'Week'
    if row["Description"] == 'Wkend':
        return 'Wkend'
    if row["Description"] == 'Q':
        return 'Quarter'
```

```
df['Description'] = df.apply(lambda row: transform(row), axis=1)
```

And this works! I'm surprised, because I only just noticed it works while giving this example on stackoverflow.

```
    Description Period_Date
0   Week        20-20
1   Wkend       21-12-2020
2   Week        42-20
3   Quarter     4
```

Now I'm totally lost, because I have more or less exactly the same dataframe (with a couple of more columns) and it just doesn't work on that one. I have absolutely no idea why.
When I select a bunch of columns from this dataframe, it works again. When I select some more columns, is doesn't work anymore..Any ideas?

Edit: To be exact, it return this df:

```
    period  value
0   Week    None
1   Wkend   21-12
2   Week    None
3   Q       4
```

So it is chaning the period column, but not the value

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
# extract period and values
s = df.period.str.extract('(\D+)(\d+-\d+)')

# where period and values are combined
mixed_period = s[0].notnull()

df['period'] = np.where(mixed_period, s[0], df['period'])
df['value'] = np.where(mixed_period, s[1], df['value'])
```

Or very similar approach with named capture group:

```
s = df.period.str.extract('(?P<period>\D+)(?P<value>\d+-\d+)')
df.update(s)
```

Output:

```
  period  value
0     Wk  20-20
1  Wkend  21-12
2     Wk  42-20
3   Year   2020
```

Comment: Thank you this certainly works. Main reason I want to try it with the .apply function is that I can convert other values as well (if period = Q it becomes quarter etc) and also to put away the code in a function nicely.
Plus it is still very peculiar why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

apply is comparatively slow. So if possible we can find an alternate as follows:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'period':['Wk20-20','Wkend', 'Wk42-20', 'Year'],
'value': [None, '21-12', None, '2020']})

new = df.period.str.split('Wk', expand=True)
df['new_value'] = np.where(df.period.str.contains('Wk\d\d-\d\d'), new[1], df.value)
df["new_period"] = np.where(df.period.str.contains('Wk\d\d-\d\d'), 'Wkend', df.period)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    period  value new_value new_period
0  Wk20-20   None     20-20      Wkend
1    Wkend  21-12     21-12      Wkend
2  Wk42-20   None     42-20      Wkend
3     Year   2020      2020       Year
```